# AWS Get VPC per region limit using AWS SDK or CLi

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I wanted to add validation to my script before starting the Pod build in AWS. 
One of the validation step is to check the # of VPCs in the asked region and the max limit set on the account.

I didn't find any CLI or SDK API to get it.

However there are similar APIs, example to get the max elastic IP per VPC, I can query:

> aws ec2 describe-account-attributes
>   And look for "AttributeName": "default-vpc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a brand new service which is able to do what you want: AWS Service Quotas.
It is currently available in most of the regions.

You can query the VPC service limit using the *GetServiceQuota* action.
The quota code for the quota *VPCs per Region* is *L-F678F1CE* (ARN: `arn:aws:servicequotas:<REGION>::vpc/L-F678F1CE`).
The service code for the service *Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC)* is *vpc*.

- Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/latest/userguide/intro.html
- GetServiceQuota-Command Documentation for the CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/service-quotas/get-service-quota.html

You can use the latest version of the aws cli as follows:
`aws service-quotas get-service-quota --service-code 'vpc' --quota-code 'L-F678F1CE'`

On Windows cli:
`aws service-quotas get-service-quota --service-code vpc --quota-code L-F678F1CE`

Answer (score 0):

As long as Trusted Advisor access to the Service Limits category remains free, you can do this:

`CHECK_ID=$(aws --region us-east-1 support describe-trusted-advisor-checks --language en --query 'checks[?name==Service Limits].{id:id}[0].id' --output text)`

`aws support describe-trusted-advisor-check-result --check-id $CHECK_ID --query 'result.sort_by(flaggedResources[?status!="ok"],&metadata[2])[].metadata' --output table --region us-east-1`

CHECK_ID is currently eW7HH0l7J9